# Calling external api in another api codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, curl

Hi we are working with api in codeigniter and fine. Our question is that how can we access api within another api codeigniter, `https://wgllocalmart.store/restprj/api/cartlist` is an api point, we want to access the another api `https://wgllocalmart.store/restprj/api/verifyCart` which accepts post data, but we are not getting any error or the response code. We have set the token globally in post man. The code is as follows

```
function cartlist(){
$data1 = "123456";
$data2 = "steve";
$data3 = "120.00";
    $post_data = '{"invoice" : "'.$data1.'" , "name" : "'.$data2.'","amount" : "'.$data3.'" }';
    
      $options = [ 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data),
          
        ]
    ];
    
     
     
    $handler = curl_init();
    $url = "https://wgllocalmart.store/restprj/api/verifyCart";
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt_array($handler, $options);
    // curl_exec($handler);
    $JSON = curl_exec($handler);
    
    //print_r(curl_getinfo($handler));
    if ($JSON === false) {
        return "CURL Error: " . curl_error($handler);
    }else{
        echo "***else";
        $outputArray = json_decode($JSON);
        print_r(curl_error($handler));
    }
}
```

we have also set errors on as

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Please suggest us the right way, why the api is not working and error is not raising. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do `$data1, $data2....` in the first line of `cartlist()` come from? Is this just a scoping issue?

Comment: Your ELSE only outputs `echo "***else";` It attempts to `json_decode()` something but it does not return that or echo that and then attempts to output a `print_r()`

Comment: There is nothing complicated about an API calling an API but if you want to know state or status of the call to the inner API you have to make sure it all gets passed back to the first API for onward transmission